# Module.exports in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, oauth2-server, meteor-restivus, restivus

I want to use [oauth2-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth2-server) in my meteor project which is an api provider implemented using [restivus](https://atmospherejs.com/nimble/restivus). In documentation for oauth2-server they specify to require the model in configuration which obviously need to export the model js file. How to use **module.export** in meteor so that I can export my model